# Datepicker is not working jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

PFB the code , but i'm unable make the calendar visible on button click.where am i going wrong ?

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
</head>
<body>
    <p>Date: <input type="button" id="datepicker"></p> 
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>  Using these CDN.

Comment: Your code will work, you should use `type="text"`, use it `//code.jquery.com` not `code.jquery.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Checkout Here](https://jsfiddle.net/uheec18b/1/)

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

You're missing the include sequence in jquery.check it now may be this is your error

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Im using your code its working fine

Comment: OP want datepicker on button click event.

Comment: ya its working for you but didn't understood where i'm going wrong .

Comment: you didnt include the jquery ui in fiddle checkout the left panel ill include your sequence is wrong wait ill updated my answer

Comment: Its working now ... issue was with ordering of CDN .

Comment: that was i said @Aditya :) check my answer

Comment: @CodingCracker pls have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28913609/how-to-use-glyphicon-instead-of-datepicker-text-box