# How to use Glyphicon instead of datepicker text box

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

PFB the link of plunker .

http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/7NgpQ/

Here I want to use -

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" id="full"></span>
```

instead of

```
<input type='text' id='full' name='fulldate'>
```

But if i use glyphicon, calendar is displaying on load only , i want to use it on selecting glyphicon icon only.Any pointers how to proceed on this.

Comment: you no need textbox there ? @Aditya you need it in `span` ?

Comment: icon is visible but calendar is also coming on load itself.I want to make the calendar to be displayed only when user clicks the calendar icon.

Comment: check this link - http://jsfiddle.net/jasenhk/oab6eyv1/  may be u need this ?

Comment: no i need to display the date month and year in three sep. text boxes,hence using the above format

Comment: but that shows correct ?